# RVM 1.0.1 installation & dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, installation, rvm

I have developed a web app in Ruby on Rails using RVM 1.0.1, Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.3. For new installations, we were getting RVM 1.0.1 from [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-1.0.1.tar.gz](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-1.0.1.tar.gz.)

Now the link is not available. Anyone please tell me where I could get the RVM 1.0.1 tar file package. Also tell me whether there would be any problem if I install an upgraded version of RVM (can cause if there are some dependencies for RVM 1.0.1). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the sources: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz

It's a source so the installation instructions might be different.

You are using very old version of RVM, it worked well with old systems available at the time (3 years ago), but it does not account for new systems available today and it most likely will fail to compile ruby on the new systems.

The current version is `1.19.5` and it can be installed using:

```
\curl -#L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enable
```

You can read more about `autolibs` here: https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs

Comment: I already got the source. But I really do appreciate your response. Thank you very much.